# Firestore: onWrite Convert Keywords Array String to Lower Case Items

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

**Scenario**

I want to able to change array of keywords to lowercase on either update or create operation, however on delete I want to exit function execution early.

**I have done the below thus far**

```
    import * as functions from "firebase-functions";
    export const onCourseCreate = functions.firestore.document("courses/{id}")
.onWrite((snap, context) => {
      return changeToLowerCase(snap);
    });

    function changeToLowerCase(
snap: functions.Change<FirebaseFirestore.DocumentSnapshot>
) {
      if (!snap.before.exists) return null;
      const original = snap.before.data();
      if (original == undefined) return;

      const _keywords: string[] = original.keywords;
      const keywords: string[] = [];
      _keywords.forEach((item: string) => {
        const lowercase = item.toLowerCase();
        keywords.push(lowercase);
      });

      return snap.after.ref.set(
        {
          keywords
        },
        { merge: true }
      );
    }
```

**Also**
I have tired `snap.after.exists`.

**The Problem**

Once I delete an item in the keywords array I go through `infinite loop`

Any suggestions I would be very much appreciative.

Thanks.

Comment: You should use `snap.after.exists`.  It will be false if onWrite represents a delete.  Are you saying that something else happens instead?  Have you tried adding logging to your function to see what it's actually receiving?

Comment: @DougStevenson your comment was an eye opener for what I was doing wrong. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

**Solution**

The problem to the above issue is that I was trying to delete an item from keywords array field. When deleting an item I am referring to the original instead I should have referred to the modified `snap.after.data()`.

It's a non general problem and it is peculiar to my specific use case. For the interested here is the final solution:

```
            import * as functions from "firebase-functions";
            export const onCourseCreate = functions.firestore.document("courses/{id}")
    .onWrite((snap, context) => {
              return changeToLowerCase(snap);
            });

            function changeToLowerCase(
snap: functions.Change<FirebaseFirestore.DocumentSnapshot>
) {
              if (!snap.after.exists) return null;

              const original = snap.before.data();
              const modified = snap.after.data();

              if (modified == undefined) return null;

              if (original != undefined && modified.keywords.length < original.keywords.length) 
        return null;

              const _keywords: string[] = modified.keywords;
              const keywords: string[] = [];
              _keywords.forEach((item: string) => {
                const lowercase = item.toLowerCase();
                keywords.push(lowercase);
              });

              return snap.after.ref.set(
                {
                  keywords
                },
                { merge: true }
              );
            }
```